# How can I grep, but hide the output

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script, which runs the `dotnet test` command.
This writes output to `stderr` in case there are any errors.

I have the following command:

```
# Run the tests.
DOTNET_TEST_OUTPUT=$(dotnet test --no-build --no-restore Restify.sln | grep "Failed!")

# If any test failed, inform the user and terminate the script.
if ! [ -z "$DOTNET_TEST_OUTPUT" ]
then
    echo -e "        \033[0;31m[ERROR]: One or more unit tests did fail.\033[0m"
    echo -e "                 \033[0;31mFor more information, execute \`dotnet test Restify.sln\` in the \`./app\` folder.\033[0m"

    # Terminate the script (with an exit code different from `0`) to notify git that this git HOOK has failed.
    # This results in the abort of the commit.
    exit 1
fi
```

When I run this script, the contents of `stderr` are echoed, but I don't want this.
However, I want to be able to `grep` the results.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use the -q switch. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104641/how-can-i-suppress-output-from-grep-so-that-it-only-returns-the-exit-status (some dummy characters)

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is bad form -- fully POSIX-compliant shells will print the `-e` as output instead of treating it as an option. Use `printf '%b\n' '...'` instead of `echo -e '...'` and it'll work reliably even on shells that follow the standard to the letter. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: Where should I append the `-q` switch exactly? After the grep still causes stderr to be echoed...

Comment: stderr doesn't go through the pipe at all in the first place; grep doesn't see it at all, and correspondingly can't check its contents or change it. That's a big part of the _whole point_ of writing things to stderr instead of stdout, so they're delivered to human operators instead of later pipeline components.

Comment: If you want to suppress stderr, that's what `2>/dev/null` _on the `dotnet` command_ is for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - If I use your suggestion on the `dotnet` command, then grep will not find anything because it's hidden. I need grep to function correctly.

Comment: That's incorrect. grep doesn't see (or match against) things on stderr even when you don't use `2>/dev/null`. So if it won't match correctly _with_ `2>/dev/null`, it wouldn't have matched correctly without it either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for the suggestions. The following does work `DOTNET_TEST_OUTPUT=$(dotnet test --no-build --no-restore Restify.sln 2>/dev/null | grep "Failed!")`.

Comment: BTW, if your `dotnet test` command is well-built, it'll have a nonzero exit status when tests fail, so you can use `if dotnet test --no-build --no-restore Restify.sln; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi` without needing any `grep` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-) I'm new to bash and I try to write a git commit hook, to ensure that the repository is in a good health before actually committing to the repository.